# Fortran shape matching rules violated

Tags: arrays, module, interface, fortran, shapes

## What am I trying to achieve

Im trying to write a subroutine that takes an Matrix (2D array) as input and prints it nicely to the standard console output.

## Problem

```
error #6634: The shape matching rules of actual arguments and dummy arguments have been violated.   ['U']
```

## Code

The subroutine printing the matrix is in this module

#### Module

```
    MODULE LinearSystems
    IMPLICIT NONE
    private
    ...
    public showMatrix
    ...
    contains
    subroutine showMatrix(a, n, m, name)
    implicit none
    double precision, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: a
    character, dimension(:), intent(in), optional :: name
    integer, intent(in) :: n,m
    integer :: i, j
    write(*,*) "*** Show Matrix ", name, " ***"
    do i = 1, n
        do j = 1, m
            write(*,'(F8.4)',advance="no") a(i,j)
        end do
        write(*,*)
    end do
    end subroutine showMatrix
```

and the main program calls it

#### Main Program

```
program PoisonEquation
    ...
    use LinearSystems
    implicit none
    double precision, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: u,...
    integer :: n = 700
    allocate(u(n-1,n-1))
    ...
    call showMatrix(u, n-1,n-1, "U")
```

I'm looking forward to receive tipps on how to improve this code snipped and get it bug free.

Comment: Show us a compilable code which fully illustrates the problem you are having.  Debugging statements such as `...` is a futile exercise, the errors are always in the code we can't see.  Incidentally, there's no need (in general) to pass the array's dimensions to a subroutine in modern Fortran.

Comment: Thank you Mark! The problem was not in the code I showed to you but in the further implementation with a name and writing a compilable code showed that to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name dummy argument is an assumed shape array (see the `dimension(:)` declaration).  The "U" literal used for the actual argument is scalar (the error message refers to this literal).

If a dummy argument is an assumed shape array, the rank of the actual argument shall be the same as the rank of the dummy argument (F2018 15.5.2.4p16).

Figure out whether you want to pass/receive an array or a scalar, and fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem solved

The problem was in the character initialisation and after fixing this issue as well as fixing a issue in the main program, which lead to u being deallocated before it was passed to the subroutine the code now works and the subroutine for printing looks like this:

```
subroutine showMatrix(a, name)
    implicit none
    double precision, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: a
    character(*), intent(in), optional :: name
    integer :: i, j
    write(*,*) "*** Show Matrix ", name, " ***"
    do i = 1, size(a,1)
        do j = 1, size(a,2)
            write(*,'(F8.4)',advance="no") a(i,j)
        end do
        write(*,*)
    end do
end subroutine showMatrix
```